# Laravel Complex Validation Rule inside Array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I wrote an API (Rest, JSON) and would like to validate incoming requests.

The API expects an field "Plan". 
Within this field, the client have two choices: "o2_Plan" or "telekom_Plan". 
One of them are required. So my validation looks like:

```
'Plan.o2_Plan' => 'required_without:Plan.telekom_Plan|array',
'Plan.telekom_Plan' => 'required_without:Plan.o2_Plan',
```

This is working fine. But there are another conditional rules within the plans:

```
'Plan.o2_Plan.tariff_variation_code' => 'required_without:Plan.o2_Plan.article_id|string',
'Plan.o2_Plan.article_id' => 'sometimes|required_without:Plan.o2_Plan.tariff_variation_code|string',
```

That means, you have to enter a tariff_variation_code OR an article_id or both of them.

But if the client only transfer the telekom_Plan (which must possible), the validation failed, with this errors:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "Plan.o2_Plan.tariff_variation_code": [
            "The tariff_variation_code field is required when article_id is not present."
        ],
        "Plan.o2_Plan.article_id": [
            "The article_id field is required when tariff_variation_code is not present."
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I achive, that the validation inside the o2_Plan only works, if the o2_Plan is present.

Thanks in advance.

best regards
Martin

Comment: It seems your validation is too complex and it can not be covered with only validation rules. I suggest using `withValidator` method https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation You can write your own validation there.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply: Thanks for your hint, I wrote a Rule for the Request, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following solution:

Changed

```
'Plan.o2_Plan' => 'required_without:Plan.telekom_Plan|array',
```

to

```
'Plan.o2_Plan' => ['required_without:Plan.telekom_Plan', 'array', new o2Plan(request('Plan.o2_Plan'))],
```

My o2Plan rule class looks like:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class o2Plan implements Rule
{
    protected $request;
    protected $message_text = '';

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @param array $request
     */
    public function __construct($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param string $attribute
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if ((!isset($this->request['tariff_variation_code']) || empty($this->request['tariff_variation_code']))
            &&
            (!isset($this->request['article_id']) || empty($this->request['article_id']))
        ) {
            $this->message_text = 'tariff_variation_code or article should not be empty';
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->message_text;
    }
}
```

And it is working fine :-)